# Typo - "question eligible for bountyin 2 days"

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, spelling

On Meta, when posting a question, the URL under the question reads "question eligible for bountyin 2 days". There is a space missing between 'bounty' and 'in'.

> [image]

Small, I know.

Comment: I soooo badly want to start a question just to test it.

Comment: Just noticed that on questions I recently posted.

Comment: That's intentional. Actually, it should read *Question ready for bountyin' in 2 days*

Comment: @mikeTheLiar that just sounds wrong hahaha

Comment: @Skippy Check the username; read the comment... check the username once more. It should click by now.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Oh you misunderstand.. I got the joke.. it's a way of saying "ready for bountying" sounds rude .. I have a dirty mind :P ..  where I live when someone says, that sounds wrong, it means it has a sexual connotation

Comment: I'll start fixing this only after someone is bountyin' this question..

Comment: Now the text is... gone1

Comment: @Undo that text can only be seen by the owner of the post. all other users see either the start bounty link or nothing (if not eligible yet...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in rev 2013.8.9.1320 (meta) / 2013.8.9.925 (sites)